# Swift: Gradient splits on rotation

Tags: swift, gradient

In short, I have a gradient that is a mix of Dark Blue and Black. The gradient looks beautiful, however when I rotate the screen and put it in landscape, the two colors split and half of the screen has a blue background and the other half is black. Figuring I didn't do it right, I copied codes from these two sources:

YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pabNgxzEaRk

Website http://blog.apoorvmote.com/gradient-background-uiview-ios-swift/

This is my code:

```
    let topColor = UIColor(red: 28/255.0, green: 25/255.0, blue: 127/255.0, alpha: 1)
    let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 25/255.0, alpha: 1)

    let gradientColors: [CGColor] = [topColor.CGColor, bottomColor.CGColor]
    let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0]

    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
    gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations

    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to stop my gradient from splitting in two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep in mind that when changing screen orientation all view's bounds change as well (assuming you are using auto layout) but the same thing is not applied on programmatically added layers. So in your case gradient layer still has the frame which is set based on old view bounds before rotation. To solve this I suggest subclassing your gradient view and update gradient layer frame in `layoutSubviews` function which is called on each view bounds change.

```
class GradientView: UIView {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = yourColors
        gradientLayer.locations = yourLocations
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You only need to override layoutSubview method to Autoresize your gradient view with respect to your device's view

Write only,

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

I tried this and its working fine. Hope this help you.